# Is it possible to use progressive with an indefinite quantity like 'many'?

Tags: perfect-continuous

Imagine that I  ordered a book  through the net 2 months ago and so far I haven't received it yet. I have been trying  to contact the seller but none of my emails has been answered. Right now I writing a new email beginning by:

> I have been sending many emails since I made my order.

Is it possible to use progressive (ongoing situation until I have received an answer or the book) with 'many' which is an indefinite quantity? I know that with a definite quantity it is better to employ present perfect simple:

> I  have read 6 books, eaten 7 apples.

Comment: As a Learner: I think it's better to use present perfect. Otherwise, It sounds as if an E-mail was sent every ten seconds. Considering a logical point of view, I think you should use present perfect. You may have sent 100 Emails, but it's not large enough to sanction using a progressive aspect.

Comment: The progressive aspect has nothing to do with having done something "enough" times. You could *be writing* a single email for an hour - or a month if you're a serious procrastinator. Anyhow, as a native speaker I would say the perfect suits this sentence better. Maybe the reason is that this email is an interruption of the process; it stands outside the previous emails because it draws attention to them. The progressive is grammatically fine, but it feels situationally wrong. P.S. I would considering opening a case about that order rather than sending yet another email.

Comment: @LukeSawczak "The progressive aspect has nothing to do with having done something", I agree. I didn't say it has something to do with ... I was saying that, if you have sent 100 E-mails every two days or so during the last month, then the number 100 is not large enough to reflect something like spamming which is conveyed when using progressive aspect.

Comment: yes but it is to emphasize the ongoing process if I  only use  present perfect the ongoing aspect will disappear and this email is not an interruption of the process and it does not stand against the previous emails but it is one email out of many others . In any case it is the last. I am going to send emails till I have received an answer , I  won't give up that is why I choose progressive.

Comment: @Cardinal That's what I understood you to mean, but neither 100 nor any other number is relevant. You can *be sending* one email over the course of a month, and you can *have sent* a million emails over the course of a month (even if these are at the extremes of slowness and quickness!).

Comment: @user5577 Fair enough, but the point of the present perfect ("I have sent") instead of the simple past ("I sent") is to carry the action forward into the present anyway. "I have sent" also implies that you're not done, so it would get the same message across. It's a question of naturalness. That said, Peter's "I have been trying to contact you" works very well, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentence

> I **have been sending** many emails since I made my order...

is correct but sounds a little odd, possibly because sending an email is a *specific* process with a *certain* time.  It sounds like you may be *spamming* them.

Usually one might say

> I **have been trying to contact** you since I made my order...

Comment: Agreed; that's a good compromise between the perceived finality of "I have sent many emails" and the oddness of "I have been sending many emails."